# Yank until end of line

Tags: vimrc

Is there a one-letter abbreviation for yank-until end of line? For example, there is:

- `D` delete til end of line
- `C` change til end of line
- `y$` was the closest thing I can find for this (`Y` yanks full line)

Is there a short-form of the above?

Comment: AFAIK, no. Workaround is "nnoremap Y y$". As suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764176/how-to-copy-from-current-position-to-the-end-of-line-in-vi

Comment: Also mentioned in `:help Y`.

Comment: For anyone else interested, bear in mind that `y$` yanks from the current cursor position until the end of the line _including the new line/line feed character._

If you don't want that, you will be using `yt$` and trying to remap that.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the "Y" is not Vi-Compatible, but you can make a work around with `:map Y y$` (Works on Neovim, not sure about vim proper)

[Source](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/416)

Comment: Yes, this works on vim, too: `:help Y`; though, `:nnoremap Y y$` is better.